# Problemas com PHP+ jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Como eu faço para pegar um valor de um botão no jquery e passar para outra pagina?

Meu problema é passar os dados do pedido que eu recebi do banco e fazer esses dados aparecerem em outra página e quero fazer por meio desse botaode +:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

faca-seu-pedido.php

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="heading step-head text-center padding-top-25 padding-bottom-25 margin-bottom-0">
                <span><?php echo $rsCat['categoria_nome']; ?></span>
            </div>
            <?php
            $sqlSubcat =  "select subcategoria_id, subcategoria_nome from subcategoria where subcategoria_habilitado='1' and subcategoria_ativo='1' and categoria_id='".$rsCat['categoria_id']."'";
            $tbSubcat = mysql_query($sqlSubcat) or die(mysql_error());

            if(mysql_num_rows($tbSubcat) > 0){
                while($rsSubcat = mysql_fetch_array($tbSubcat)){
            ?>
                    <h6 class="step-head text-center padding-bottom-10"><?php echo $rsSubcat['subcategoria_nome']; ?></h6>
                    <ul class="pizza-flavers">
                        <?php
                        $sqlItem = "select item_id, item_nome, item_descricao, item_preco from item where item_habilitado='1' and item_ativo='1' and categoria_id='".$rsCat['categoria_id']."' and subcategoria_id='".$rsSubcat['subcategoria_id']."' order by item_nome";
                        $tbItem = mysql_query($sqlItem) or die(mysql_error());
                        if(mysql_num_rows($tbItem) > 0){
                            $i=1;
                            while($rsItem = mysql_fetch_array($tbItem)){

                        ?>
                        <li>
```

Ele seleciona o item, e os inputs, o problema é: quando eu clicar no + eu quero que ele a identifique e quando eu clicar no finalizar ele deve aparecer com esses dados que eu solucionei em outra pagina:

Javascript do botao "+"

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".pizza-add-sub").append('<div class="plus qty-pizza">+</div><div class="mines qty-pizza">-</div>');
  $(".qty-pizza").on("click", function() {

    var $button = $(this);
    var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
    if ($button.text() == "+") {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
      // Don't allow decrementing below zero
      if (oldValue > 0) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
      } else {
        newVal = 0;
      }
    }
    $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);

    var valorTotal = 0;
    var valoresMultiplicar = 0;
    $(".qtdpedidos").each(function() {
      valorTotal += parseFloat($(this).data("preco") * $(this).val());
    })

    $(".item span").each(function() {
      valoresMultiplicar += parseFloat($(this).html());
    })

    if (valorTotal==0){
        $("#tot").text("");
        $("#resultado").text('');
    }else{
        $("#tot").text('R$'+(parseFloat(valorTotal+5).toFixed(2)));
        $("#resultado").text('R$'+parseFloat(valorTotal).toFixed(2));
    }




  });
});
```

Qando ele aparetar no botado de "Finalizar" ele devera aparecer somente o que eu solucionei em outra pagina:

Pagina que deve aparecer os dados:

Tela de confirmação de pedidos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia,

Você pode utilizar uma classe de sessão, você ontem o identificador do seu produto, e guarda em um array o seu objeto completo, logo após, você envia a um método que irá registrar isto na sessão usando session_start no php.

Com jQuery você teria de montar um arquivo que recebia via post, aí você usaria ajax e enviaria por post, mas neste segundo caso também utilizando session para não perder o que se foi incluído.

Vou tentar criar um exemplo assim que chegar no computador e te envio por este post.

Comment: No aguardo Marcus.